# Can't login to mailbox using Postfix/Dovecot/MySQL: “Failed to initialize quota”

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to setup my own mail server and I am stuck on one Dovecot error, “Error: Failed to initialize quota.” Anyone have a solution?

```
Feb 16 01:10:25 outgoing dovecot: imap(ichanged@original.domain)<13083><PzPpt/eBKIofusGT>:
Error: Failed to initialize quota: Quota root User quota: dict quota init failed: dict_init(sqlquota) failed: Dictionary URI is missing ':': sqlquota
```

**EDIT:**

Here is dovecot sql settings

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=mail_server user=mail password=password
default_pass_scheme = BLF-CRYPT
iterate_query = SELECT username AS user FROM mailbox
user_query = SELECT CONCAT('/var/mail/vmail/',maildir) AS home, CONCAT('maildir:/var/mail/vmail/',maildir) AS mail, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid, CONCAT('*:bytes=',quota) AS quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = 1
password_query = SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active='1'
```

Comment: Have you done a Google search for “[Error: Failed to initialize quota](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%E2%80%9CError:+Failed+to+initialize+quota.%E2%80%9D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).”?

Comment: @JakeGould, yep. Found something but it doesn't help, that's why i wrote here.

Answer (score 0):

You activate the quota, but probably forgot to configure.

If you want to configure, follow theses instructions, they are generally written to the /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-quota.conf:

https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Dict

But if you want to disable, execute a **grep -R 'quota'** in your dovecot directory, and comment, or remove the occurrences, like:

```
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota # change this
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins # to this
```